# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.io' for json_normalize

Tags: pandas, normalize

Please read carefully. In my Python script I have the following:

```
import json 
import pandas
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

and it returns the following error:

> from pandas.io.json import json_normalize  ModuleNotFoundError: No
>   module named 'pandas.io'; 'pandas' is not a package

My steps:

- I have uninstalled and installed Pandas
- I have upgraded pip and pandas
- I have installed io (`pip install -U pandas.io`)
- I have installed data_reader and replaced the pandas.io.json part with that: `from pandas_datareader import json_normalize`

I have tried every solution I saw on stackoverflow and github and nothing worked. The only one I have not tried is installing Anaconda but it should work with what I tried before. Do you think it is a Windows setting things I must change?

PS: My Python version is 3.7.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

Go to ...\Lib\site-packages\pytrends on your local disk and open file request.py

Change

```
from pandas.io.json._normalize import nested_to_record
```

to

```
from pandas.io.json.normalize import nested_to_record
```

I had the same error, but it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

also change

from pandas.io.json.normalize

to

from pandas.io.json._normalize

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem was the fact that the python file had the name pandas. The filename was `pandas.py`. After renaming it, the code worked normally without errors.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem and i solve it b uninstalling extra python versions install on my windows.now i have only one python installed by anaconda,and everything is working perfectly